# The Weird BigInteger.mod Modulus Method

Tags: java, biginteger, modular

In Java, we know if we want to compare two reference objects, we usually need to use `equals`, but here I am so confused about the output of the following:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("0") == BigInteger.ZERO);                     // false
System.out.println(new BigInteger("0").mod(BigInteger.ONE) == BigInteger.ZERO); // true
```

Why is the second statement true?

Comment: `==` is evil and can sometimes trick you into believing that it works.  Just don't pay attention to its output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took a while, but following the logical paths of the execution takes us to:

[MutableBigInteger#toBigInteger(int sign)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/math/MutableBigInteger.java#MutableBigInteger.toBigInteger%28int%29)

Which has the following statement:

```
BigInteger toBigInteger(int sign) {
    if (intLen == 0 || sign == 0)
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    return new BigInteger(getMagnitudeArray(), sign);
}
```

So in this case, the constant `BigInteger.ZERO` is returned, so the statement is true.

Stack trace:

```
BigInteger#mod(BigInteger)
BigInteger#remainder(BigInteger)
BigInteger#remainderKnuth(BigInteger)
MutableBigInteger#toBigInteger(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a three method implementation :

```
public BigInteger mod(BigInteger m) {
if (m.signum <= 0)
    throw new ArithmeticException("BigInteger: modulus not positive");

BigInteger result = this.remainder(m);     // call remainder()
return (result.signum >= 0 ? result : result.add(m));  
}



public BigInteger remainder(BigInteger val) {
    MutableBigInteger q = new MutableBigInteger(),
                      a = new MutableBigInteger(this.mag),
                      b = new MutableBigInteger(val.mag);

    return a.divide(b, q).toBigInteger(this.signum); // call toBigInteger()
}



BigInteger toBigInteger(int sign) {
    if (intLen == 0 || sign == 0)
        return BigInteger.ZERO;    // here is your answer.
    return new BigInteger(getMagnitudeArray(), sign);
}
```